# JavaScript: compare two arrays and print the number of matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-comparison

I´m Staked in this, I have to compare two arrays and display how many matches are in total, but is not working and I don´t know why. I really appreciate any tip on this

```js
/*creating the function to check the lottery results */
function checkNumbers(_customerNumber, _winningNumers) {
    var matches = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < getCustomerNumber.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < getCustomerNumber.length; j++) {
        if (getCustomerNumber[i] == getWinningNumbers[j]) matches++;
      }
    }
    return matches;
  }
  /*getting the customer number*/

function getCustomerNumber() {
  return ['12', '17', '24', '37', '38', '43'];
}

/*array to return the winning numbers*/

function getWinningNumbers() {
  return ['12', '17', '24', '37', '38', '43'];
}

function displayResult() {
  var winningMessage = "This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n" + getWinningNumbers() + "\n";
  var customerMessage = "The Customer's Number is:\n" + getCustomerNumber() + "\n";
  var numbersMatched = "Numbers Matched\n" + checkNumbers
  alert(winningMessage + customerMessage + numbersMatched);
}

function init() {
  displayResult();
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: `checkNumbers` is a function ...you have to call it `checkNumbers()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter` to get filtered list and `.indexOf` to check if value exist in another array.

```js
let arr1 = ['12', '17', '24', '37', '38', '43'],
  arr2 = ['22', '47', '24', '38', '38', '44'];

var matches = arr1.filter(function(item){
  return arr2.indexOf(item) > -1
})
console.log(matches)
console.log("Total matches: ", matches.length)
```

Also `window.onload` is not a good practice. This will replace all the previous handlers. You should use

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){...})
```

#### Your code revamped

```js
/* creating thefunction to check the lottery results */
function checkNumbers(_customerNumber, _winningNumers) {
    return _customerNumber.filter(function(x) {
      return _winningNumers.indexOf(x)
    }).length
  }
  /* getting the customer number */

function getCustomerNumber() {
  return ['12', '17', '24', '37', '38', '43'];
}

/* array toreturn the winning numbers */

function getWinningNumbers() {
  return ['12', '17', '24', '37', '38', '43'];
}

function displayResult() {
  var winNum = getWinningNumbers();
  var custNum = getCustomerNumber();
  var winningMessage = "This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n" + winNum + "\n";
  var customerMessage = "The Customer's Number is:\n" + custNum + "\n";
  var numbersMatched = "Numbers Matched\n" + checkNumbers(custNum, winNum)
  console.log(winningMessage, customerMessage, numbersMatched);
}

function init() {
  displayResult();
}
window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, but they teach us this window.onload at Uni, and if you try something different, you don´t have all the points....

Comment: @LuciaVazquez I understand that. But just remember this point for future. Also I have updated your code and added in my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

One common mistake of calling function without () everywhere.

Another one is that you should declare all your function on the top in javascript as this is an interpreted language and function should be declared first before using it.

your code should be like this.

```js
function getWinningNumbers() {
  return ['12', '17', '24', '37', '38', '43'];
}

function getCustomerNumber() {
  return ['12', '17', '24', '37', '38', '43'];
}

function checkNumbers() {
    var matches = 0;
    var customerNumbers = getCustomerNumber();
    var winningNumbers = getWinningNumbers();

    for (var i = 0; i < customerNumbers.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < winningNumbers.length; j++) {
        if (customerNumbers[i] == winningNumbers[j]) {
          matches++;
        }
      }
    }
    return matches;
  }
  /*getting the customer number*/

function displayResult() {
  var winningMessage = "This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n" + getWinningNumbers() + "\n";
  var customerMessage = "The Customer's Number is:\n" + getCustomerNumber() + "\n";
  var numbersMatched = "Numbers Matched\n" + checkNumbers();
  console.log(winningMessage + customerMessage + numbersMatched);
}

function init() {
  displayResult();
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: This is perfect Deep, Thank you so much, I know I have done stupid mistakes, but I´m just starting with code. Thanks I´ll pick your tips and don´t do this mistakes again

Comment: Just a pointer @Deep, `checkNumbers` can be a generic function and fetching arrays from `getWinningNumbers()` multiple times does not makes that much sense. Rather save them in variable and pass them to `checkNumbers` as arguments.

Comment: @Rajesh agreed, i also tried similar the same within the checkNumbers function but yeah i could have send it while calling checkNumbers itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr1 = ['12', '17', '24', '37', '38', '43'],
    arr2 = ['22', '47', '24', '38', '38', '44'];

function getMatch(arr1, arr2) {
    let matched = 0;
    arr1.forEach(i => {
        if (~arr2.indexOf(i)) {
            matched++;
        }
    });
    return matched;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sarkis,Thanks for your reply, I think I have explained wrong, I´m looking for the number of matches (in this case 6, not for the numbers that are the same). Thank you :)

Comment: in that case you can just return ```tmpArr.length```

Comment: or use function above, I improved it a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Try with in a `function()` like this.its all function so.apply with function declaration of all place .its working now.

```js
var matches = 0
function checkNumbers (_customerNumber,_winningNumers)
{
 

for (var i=0;i<getCustomerNumber().length;i++) {
    for (var j=0;j<getWinningNumbers().length;j++) {
        if(getCustomerNumber()[i]==getWinningNumbers()[j]) {matches++; console.log(getWinningNumbers()[i])}
      
    }
}
return matches; 
}
/*getting the customer number*/

function getCustomerNumber()
{
return ['12','17','24','37','38','43'];
}

/*array to return the winning numbers*/

function getWinningNumbers ()
{
return ['12','17','24','37','38','43'];
}
function displayResult()
{
var winningMessage =  "This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n" +      getWinningNumbers()+ "\n";
var customerMessage = "The Customer's Number is:\n" + getCustomerNumber()+ "\n";
var numbersMatched = "Numbers Matched\n" + checkNumbers();
alert(winningMessage + customerMessage + numbersMatched);
}
function init()
{
displayResult();
}
window.onload = init;
```

***alternate*** try this is function  `checkNumbers()` both are function so not getting a length.so try with array its working

```js
var matches = 0;
function checkNumbers ()
{

for (var i=0; i<getCustomerNumber.length;i++) {
    for (var j=0;j<getCustomerNumber.length;j++) {
        if(getCustomerNumber[i]==getWinningNumbers[j]){ matches ++;}
     
    }
}
return matches;
}
/*getting the customer number*/

var getCustomerNumber = ['12','17','24','37','38','43'];


var getWinningNumbers = ['12','17','24','37','38','43'];

function displayResult()
{
var winningMessage =  "This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n" +      getWinningNumbers+ "\n";
var customerMessage = "The Customer's Number is:\n" + getCustomerNumber+ "\n";
var numbersMatched = "Numbers Matched\n" + checkNumbers();
alert(winningMessage + customerMessage + numbersMatched);
}
function init()
{
displayResult();
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Thank you prasad. I have tried this one before, but if I put them as variables, I can´t display it as is telling me that they are not a function

Comment: see my updated answer.i was added with answer of both function  & array